# Ubuntu Touch Kernel Config [easy question]

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-touch, porting

I'm in the process of porting Ubuntu touch.  Based on the porting guide, https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/#anchor4
I would like to know which kernel is it talking about in the kernel config section.

**kernel**/[manufacturer]/[codename]/arch/arm/configs/ cyanogenmod_[codename]_defconfig

a) The Ubuntu Kernel (if so, which release/version)

b) Cyanogenmod Kernel for the device I am porting the device to

c) Android Kernel (generic)

d) Something else?

I am confused about this because there was no relevant kernel folder that was actually made at the time the phablet folder was setup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your port is based on CyanogenMod, then - "b) Cyanogenmod Kernel for the device I am porting the device to".